# Opening shapefile linked custom metadata textfile within QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, metadata, actions

I used a text file as a simple metadata for my shapefiles. It has basic information such as Source of raw data, Who can edit the file, Accuracy level, what those dbf filed means, Cost aquiring data, etc.

The text file is saved with the same name and path with my Shapefile e.g.

- Conservation Area.shp
- Conservation area.txt     ----> the file

How do I open this text file when its shapefile is an active layer?

I know, the perfect solution would be to use standard metadata format (shp.xml) or learn to write a plugin.

Temporarily, I'm doing it as follows.

Create field named "meta" in the shapefile and populate EVERY row of the field with path and filename of the textfile.Then Create action > type : "Windows", action: notepad "[% "meta" %]

To View,  I select the new action Icon and click on any vector.

I am using win 7, x64, QGIS 2.10.

Answer (score 2):

There is a meta data file extension for the shape file format called shp.xml:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

There is also a plugin to QGIS called Metatools, that will let you write and view data to and from the shp.xml file.

Comment: Metatools and Qsphere plugin is nice as it follows a proper standard but I just need something simple & easy.